# What are the best ways to solve discrete divide and conquer recurrences?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, algorithms

What is the best way to solve discrete divide and conquer recurrences?

The "Master Theorem" is one way.

What other ways are available?

Answer (score 1):

The current issue of the
Journal of the ACM (JACM),
Volume 60 Issue 3, June 2013,
has this article:

"A Master Theorem for Discrete Divide and Conquer Recurrences",
by
MICHAEL DRMOTA, TU Wien
and
WOJCIECH SZPANKOWSKI, Purdue University

Abstract:
Divide-and-conquer recurrences are one of the most studied equations in computer science. Yet, discrete
versions of these recurrences, namely
$$T(n) = a_n
+
\sum_{j=1}^m
b_j
T(
\lfloor
p_j
n+δ_j
\rfloor
)
+
\sum_{j=1}^m
\bar b_j
T(
\lceil
p_j
n+\bar δ_j
\rceil)
$$
for some known sequence $a_n$ and given 
$b_j$
,$\bar b_j$
, $p_j$
and $δ_j$
, $\bar δ_j$
, present some challenges. The discrete nature of
this recurrence (represented by the ﬂoor and ceiling functions) introduces certain oscillations not captured
by the traditional Master Theorem, for example due to Akra and Bazzi [1998] who primary studied the
continuous version of the recurrence. We apply powerful techniques such as Dirichlet series, Mellin-Perron
formula, and (extended) Tauberian theorems of Wiener-Ikehara to provide a complete and precise solution
to this basic computer science recurrence. We illustrate applicability of our results on several examples
including a popular and fast arithmetic coding algorithm due to Boncelet for which we estimate its average
redundancy and prove the Central Limit Theorem for the phrase length. To the best of our knowledge,
discrete divide and conquer recurrences were not studied in this generality and such detail; in particular,
this allows us to compare the redundancy of Boncelet’s algorithm to the (asymptotically) optimal Tunstall
scheme.